# Post Installation Access

Tags: system-installation

After installing Ubuntu 16.04, is there a way to access the system vi ssh or telnet or some other method that doesnt require a monitor and keyboard. It seems impossible that nothing is included with the base system

Comment: Not sure, if you need the system to do specific things then you usually have to install packages to do that - in this case, you don't need to install packages to SSH from an Ubuntu computer but you do need to install SSH on the computer you want to SSH into. How did you install without a monitor and keyboard? If you can attach a keyboard and monitor and install OpenSSH (you don't need Internet on the machine to be able to do this, just on a different machine) then I can give you an answer, but I don't think it will be possible without that.

Answer (score 3):

**The base Ubuntu desktop system does not contain a way to get shell access over the network by default.** You have to install the `openssh-server` package to get that ability.